# Event listener which detects that :focus-within lost focus

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been trying to detect whether `:focus-within` class was lost. I tried to detect click-outside of by using addEventListener for 'click', 'auxclick', 'blur', 'mouseup'. But I can't figure out how to detect a click outside of the actual document. For example, click on URL input. How can I solve it?

Comment: Could you explain more in details so that everyone can understand the question in an easy way and provide you best solution on it ?

Comment: The event you need is `focusout` and the test you want to do when the event occurs is `event.target.matches(':focus-within')`. Actions that don't actually remove focus (like you describe) cannot be listened to.

Answer (score 9):

To detect whether a DOM element has lost `:focus-within`, you can use the `focusout` event like this:

```js
containerElement.addEventListener('focusout', function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.contains(e.relatedTarget)) {
        /* Focus will still be within the container */
    } else {
        /* Focus will leave the container */
    }
});
```

When focus is lost by the page altogether (visiting an URL, switching tabs, etc.), `e.relatedTarget` doesn't exist so the code just works. If you want to *ignore* when the page loses focus, you can use `document.hasFocus()` to check:

```js
containerElement.addEventListener('focusout', function(e) {
    /*
        If the document has lost focus,
        skip the containment check 
        and keep the element visible.
     */
    if (!document.hasFocus()) {
        return;
    }
    if (!e.currentTarget.contains(e.relatedTarget)) {
        hideSelf();
    }
});
```

...but then you have to react when the focus *does* get back to the page, so the full(er) solution looks something like this:

```js
containerElement.addEventListener('focusout', function(e) {
    const self = e.currentTarget;
    /*
        If the document has lost focus,
        don't hide the container just yet,
        wait until the focus is returned.
     */
    if (!document.hasFocus()) {
        window.addEventListener('focus', function focusReturn() {
            /* 
                We want the listener to be triggered just once,
                so we have it remove itself from the `focus` event.
            */
            window.removeEventListener('focus', focusReturn);

            /*
                Test whether the active element 
                is within our container.
             */
            if (!self.contains(document.activeElement)) {
                hideSelf();
            }
        });
        return;
    }
    if (!self.contains(e.relatedTarget)) {
        hideSelf();
    }
});
```